Next js 14.1.4 npm run build issue like The "next export" command has been removed in favor of "output: export" in next.config.js
Hello i am new to front end next js deplyoment
currently, i have created one next js application with version 14.1.4
and to build deployment i am using this command
npm run build
but it is giving below error
The "next export" command has been removed in favor of "output: export" in next.config.js. Learn more: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export
below is my next.config.js file can someone please help me to resolve this issue
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    async rewrites() {
        return [{
            source: "/(t|T)(e|E)(x|X)(t|T)",
            destination: "/text"
        }]
    },
    images: {
        domains: [
            'naturalproduct.s3.amazonaws.com',
            'naturalproductproduction.s3.amazonaws.com',
            'naturalproductstaging.s3.amazonaws.com',
            'naturalproducttest.s3.amazonaws.com',
            'cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com',
            'static.vecteezy.com']
    },
    experimental: {
        missingSuspenseWithCSRBailout: false,
    },
    env: getEnvConfig()
}

module.exports = nextConfig

function getEnvConfig() {
    const dotenv = require('dotenv');

    const environment = process.env.TARGET_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV;
    const envFilePath = `.env.${environment}`;

    try {
        const result = dotenv.config({ path: envFilePath });
        if (result.error) {
            throw result.error;
        }
        return result.parsed;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(`Error loading environment variables from ${envFilePath}: ${err.message}`);
        return {};
    }
}


Does this answer your question? While deploying nextjs app throwing error: The "next export" command has been removed in favor of "output: export" in next.config.js
